# Why does tmux ignore PATH when starting shell?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, tmux

- System: macOS 10.12
- Tmux version: 2.6

As a macports user, I have `/opt/local/bin` at the beginning of my `PATH`. However, when starting `tmux`, it uses `/bin/bash` instead of `/opt/local/bin/bash`, indeed, the `SHELL` variable also points there. This confuses me and causes some `.bashrc` settings to break because the version is outdated.

I know I can set the path to tmux's default shell `set-option -g default-shell`, but I use my `.tmux.conf` on different systems, so it should be OS-agnostic and simply use the shell one would get when executing `bash`.

I have all my settings in `.bashrc` and source this file in `.bash_login` und `.bash_profile`, so my `PATH` should be available to `tmux`.

How can I solve this?

It seems that `SHELL` is always `/bin/bash`, not sure why. My terminal is configured to start `/opt/local/bin/bash -l` at startup.

Comment: "However, when starting `tmux`, it uses `/bin/bash` instead of `/opt/local/bin/bash`, indeed, the `SHELL` variable also points there." – Which of the two paths do you refer to by "there"? Do you mean the `SHELL` variable after `tmux` and the new shell starts? or before? (i.e. in the old shell, if you invoke `tmux` from already existing shell). Do you use `tmux` as a login shell? If not, what is your login shell and what is the `SHELL` variable in it? (before you invoke `tmux` from it).

Comment: It seems that `SHELL` is always `/bin/bash`, not sure why. My terminal is configured to start `/opt/local/bin/bash -l` at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [`man 1 tmux`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) says about `default-shell` in Linux. I expect `tmux` in macOS to behave similarly:

> `default-shell path`
>
> Specify the default shell. This is used as the login shell for new windows when the `default-command` option is set to empty, and must be the full path of the executable. When started `tmux` tries to set a default value from the first suitable of the `SHELL` environment variable, the shell returned by `getpwuid(3)`, or `/bin/sh`. This option should be configured when `tmux` is used as a login shell.

As you can see, none of these methods uses `$PATH`. Additionally from [`bash` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables):

> `SHELL`
>
> The full pathname to the shell is kept in this environment variable. If it is not set when the shell starts, Bash assigns to it the full pathname of the current user’s login shell.

Either way it's your login shell what matters and it's not `/opt/local/bin/bash`. You may consider overwriting `SHELL` with `$BASH` in your `.bashrc`:

```
SHELL="$BASH"
```

Note: I haven't tested this against side effects. There's one peculiarity (at least in my Kubuntu) with this. If `tmux` is already running for your user then changes to `SHELL` will not affect additional invocations. This is because an additional `tmux` invocation works along with the first `tmux` and it's the first `tmux` that handles everything (I can see this with `pstree`); its environment doesn't change when you invoke an additional one.

However this way of invoking `tmux` should honor your `$PATH`, regardless of `$SHELL` etc.:

```
tmux new-session bash
```

Comment: Setting the `SHELL` variable solves my problem for now.

Comment: you set SHELL variable in what file? @oarfish

Comment: In `.bashrc` which I'm sourcing in `.bash_login` to have the stuff be read by tmux.